# How to optimize mysqldump which is not allowing to connect to database when run

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04, mysqldumpslow

I am facing issue of mysqldump, when I try to backup db (which is more than 200GB) using mysqldump it stops my connection to databass. I keep getting error of "too many connection", website also does not load, give error unable to connect to db. Apache logs also showing same

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections in
```

I have increased mysql connection as below but still facing same issue

```
[mysqld]
max_connections = 1000
max_allowed_packet=500M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_log_file_size = 1000M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

Should I increase max_connections further. how many connection I can increase or what will be issue if increase it to further. Also mysqldump take backup very slow.
`your text`
Please note all tables are innodb engine.I have tried to increase max_connections to 1000 but still not resolved

Comment: Are your tables INNODB or MYISAM?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12210/too-many-connections-when-running-mysqldump

Comment: @RiggsFolly All tables are INNODB

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-performance